# Extracting multiple webpages (1 Website, Multiple Tabs to select) into Excel with a macro

Tags: excel, web, vba

I am new to learning and understanding macros and am quite eager to learn!

I am trying to extract data in the form of tables from 1 website but from multiple pages. Below is the first webpage

1st Webpage - http://www.foxsports.com/college-basketball/abilene-christian-wildcats-team-stats?season=2014&category=SCORING&type=1

I am looking to extract just the table from this webpage.. After that has been done, on the right side above the table you can see a drop down box with multiple selections (Teams). I would then like to continue getting the tables for each team (So from Abilene Christian --> Youngstown State)

I hope I have provided enough clarity to be able to receive some help and feedback!

Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to SO! There are many examples available freely through a little searching on your own that can help you get you started on your own project. If and when you run into trouble, come back and show your original effort, noting where the problem is and what error messages you have received.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I have been able to come up with thus so far! I don't know how to get it to loop or be able to get all the data I am looking for.. This is only getting the table for 1 of the many webpages I need...

```
Sub BasketballStats()

    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim TR_col As Object, TR As Object
    Dim TD_col As Object, TD As Object
    Dim row As Long, col As Long

    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.foxsports.com/college-basketball/louisiana-tech-bulldogs-team-stats?season=2015&category=SCORING&type=1", False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlHttp.send

    Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.ResponseText

    Dim tbl As Object
    Set tbl = html.getElementById("curr_table")

    row = 1
    col = 1

    Set TR_col = html.getelementsbytagname("TR")
    For Each TR In TR_col
        Set TD_col = TR.getelementsbytagname("TD")
        For Each TD In TD_col
            Cells(row, col) = TD.innerText
            col = col + 1
        Next
        col = 1
        row = row + 1
    Next
End Sub
```